Can not download package "gensim" on Mac Pycharm
I tried to download the gensim package for topic modelling, but every attempt failed. Below is the error message I got.
Collecting gensim
  Using cached gensim-4.3.3.tar.gz (23.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.18.5 (from gensim)
  Using cached numpy-1.26.4.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      + /Users/apple/PycharmProjects/Dissertation_Sustainability/.venv/bin/python /private/var/folders/r_/h00msdk579ddyzx_lzzb9vw00000gp/T/pip-install-otmvs8e2/numpy_2031f30054c149319b6c7d6504d69e62/vendored-meson/meson/meson.py setup /private/var/folders/r_/h00msdk579ddyzx_lzzb9vw00000gp/T/pip-install-otmvs8e2/numpy_2031f30054c149319b6c7d6504d69e62 /private/var/folders/r_/h00msdk579ddyzx_lzzb9vw00000gp/T/pip-install-otmvs8e2/numpy_2031f30054c149319b6c7d6504d69e62/.mesonpy-l_92j_hs -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/private/var/folders/r_/h00msdk579ddyzx_lzzb9vw00000gp/T/pip-install-otmvs8e2/numpy_2031f30054c149319b6c7d6504d69e62/.mesonpy-l_92j_hs/meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.99
      Source dir: /private/var/folders/r_/h00msdk579ddyzx_lzzb9vw00000gp/T/pip-install-otmvs8e2/numpy_2031f30054c149319b6c7d6504d69e62
      Build dir: /private/var/folders/r_/h00msdk579ddyzx_lzzb9vw00000gp/T/pip-install-otmvs8e2/numpy_2031f30054c149319b6c7d6504d69e62/.mesonpy-l_92j_hs
      Build type: native build
      Project name: NumPy
      Project version: 1.26.4
      
      ../meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['nvc'], ['pgcc'], ['icc'], ['icx']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `nvc --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvc'"
      Running `pgcc --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgcc'"
      Running `icc --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'icc'"
      Running `icx --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'icx'"
      
      A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/r_/h00msdk579ddyzx_lzzb9vw00000gp/T/pip-install-otmvs8e2/numpy_2031f30054c149319b6c7d6504d69e62/.mesonpy-l_92j_hs/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

I looked up and already installed SciPy and NumPy, also upgraded by PIP, but I still got the above error message. It looks different to the error message I got before I download the two packages, but I'm not sure how to resolve this further.

What command(s) have you tried to trigger download & installation? What version of Python is in the environment you are installing into? The error looks like the install may be trying to locally-compile parts of the library, implying your attempt hasn't succeeded in finding a precompiled package that matches your system & Python – and usually precompiled packages offer the smoothest experience. Rolling back to an older Python version might find a precompiled package that works. Alternatively, ensuring a full set of MacOS build utilities present might allow local compilation.
